# Is there a way to use hyphens in a Symfony2 2.3 route placeholder?

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I'm trying to use a hyphenated name in my route placeholder, such as `new-jersey`, but I am getting a 404 error. When I use a single world in my placeholder, such as `illinois`, the route works correctly.

Is this because PHP is erroring-out by trying to handle a hyphenated placeholder variable such as `new-jersey`? Is there a way I can pass hyphenated variables into a routing placeholder?

My relevant route is set up as such:

```
# routing.yml
bar_exam_show:
    path: /pass-the-bar-exam/{statePath}-bar-exam
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:BarExams:show }
```

So to recap:

```
/illinois-bar-exam          #200 OK
/new-jersey-bar-exam        #404 Not Found
/district-of-columbia       #404 Not Found
```

**Edit - Contents of UrlMatcher.php**

```
if (0 === strpos($pathinfo, '/pass-the-bar-exam')) {
    // bar_exams_index
    if ($pathinfo === '/pass-the-bar-exam') {
        return array (  '_controller' => 'AppBundle\\Controller\\BarExamsController::indexAction',  '_route' => 'bar_exams_index',);
    }

    // bar_exams_show
    if (preg_match('#^/pass\\-the\\-bar\\-exam/(?P<statePath>[^/\\-]++)\\-bar\\-exam$#s', $pathinfo, $matches)) {
        return $this->mergeDefaults(array_replace($matches, array('_route' => 'bar_exams_show')), array (  '_controller' => 'AppBundle\\Controller\\BarExamsController::showAction',));
    }

}
```

Comment: Go into your cache and open the cached UrlMatcher.  Search for `bar_exam_show`.  Above it will be a `strpos` and a `preg_match`.  Show us that regular expression.

Comment: I've updated the question with the relevant lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is strange that symfony added the exclusion for hyphens in the cache.  You must be using a much older version because it doesn't do that any more.

Anyway, adding this requirement should override the default expression.

```
bar_exam_show:
    path: /pass-the-bar-exam/{statePath}-bar-exam
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:BarExams:show }
    requirements:
        page:  [^\/]+
```

Comment: I probably should have specified the version in the question. We are using Symfony 2.3. It's nice to know this is no longer an issue in the newer versions. I've edited the title of the question to be more accurate.